# "500 Backend Error" using Gmail API - safe to retry?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I'm sending messages via the Gmail API. In particular, I am trying to send 5-7 emails from the same account to different users (1 each) within about 2 seconds.

About 8% of those emails are failing with this error:

```
&googleapi.Error{
    Code:500, 
    Message:"Backend Error", Body:`{
        "error": {
            "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "backendError",
                "message": "Backend Error"
            }
            ],
            "code": 500,
            "message": "Backend Error"
        }
    }`, 
    Header:http.Header(nil),
    Errors:[]googleapi.ErrorItem{
        googleapi.ErrorItem{Reason:"backendError", Message:"Backend Error"}
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem like it's specific to a particular account, as 6/7 emails may succeed.

I'm hesitant to retry this for fear of sending 2 emails to the same person.

Is there any way to tell whether this message is safe to retry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it can happen before send and sometimes after send.

I logged the "To" and "From" from five different email attempts that all received a 500 Backend Error. None of these attempts made it to the "Sent" folder of my inbox. I conclude that they were never sent, and it's safe to retry these messages. However, other people in the comments (see below) indicated that the messages actually made it to the remote mailbox, and it's not safe to retry.

Comment: Hey Kevin, this is not necessarily true, we've had conditions where it will send and you will get a 500 backend error. Highly recommend running your checks to ensure that you do not send duplicate emails as this type of error means that Google's code screwed up and you have no idea where it did (pre-send or post-send).

Comment: You should also stagger your emails for a particular Gmail account. As sometimes I'll see 500 Backend Error display when you're hitting the the Send API too frequently (I believe the safe limit is 1 every 3-4 seconds).

Answer (score 6):

> "code": 500, "message": "Backend Error"

Is basically an issue with Google server.  Either the request you are making took to long or the server preforming the request is busy and the request again took to long.   It doesn't sound like what you are doing should be causing the problem.

Tips when not to run: Don't run on the hour you will be completing with everyone who has cron jobs set up also don't run at midnight (PDT) as this is when quotas reset and again you will be completing with everyone who blew out yesterdays quota.

Solution:

The normal solution is to wait a few seconds then send the same request again. (Implementing [Exponential Backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff))

The flow for implementing simple exponential backoff is as follows.

1. Make a request to the API
2. Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
3. Wait 1s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
4. Retry request
5. Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
6. Wait 2s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
7. Retry request
8. Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
9. Wait 4s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
10. Retry request
11. Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
12. Wait 8s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
13. Retry request
14. Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
15. Wait 16s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
16. Retry request

If you still get an error, stop and log the error.

Comment: > The normal solution is to wait a few seconds then send the same request again.

Right but the problem is the error message is so vague that I have no idea whether it *actually* sent or not. Easy to imagine the message being sent and some other error causing a 500. I don't have inside information. Do you work there and know better?

Comment: That is a Google error. No I don't work for Google but I have been working with Google APIs for five years.

Comment: Forgot about this i wrote this blog post a few weeks ago on the same subject http://www.daimto.com/google-apis-flood-buster/

Comment: You're still not answering my question - the error does not make it clear whether it is safe to retry.

Comment: As I said Google recommends you implementing exponential back off check the documentation on any Google api for 500 error http://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/errors#backoff